# Access $_SESSION via Wordpress REST Api with credentials include

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I've got a session token for a third party api stored in a $_SESSION variable and want to be able to access it within a WP Rest request. Can I do this my using WP Rest's built in [Nonce authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/)?

First I create a `wp_rest` nonce and `l10n` it for the script:

```php
$params = array(
  'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
);
wp_localize_script( 'my_script', 'user_tools', $params );
```

Here's the request:

```js
on('submit', '#mzStudioRegisterForm', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let form = event.target;
  let data = new FormData(form);
  data.append('_wpnonce', user_tools.nonce);
 fetch(base_url + `registeruser?`, {method: 'POST', body: data, credentials: 'include'})
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(json => console.log({"json": json}));
});
```

The rest route and callback are minimal:

```php
function register_user_with_studio() {
  // An example with 0 parameters.
  register_rest_route(
    'myplugin-auth/v1',
    '/registeruser',
    array(
      'methods'             => \WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
      'callback'            => __NAMESPACE__ . '\register_user',
      'permission_callback' => '__return_true'
    )
  );
}
```

The callback:

```php
function add_user_to_studio( $request ) {
  $params = $request->get_body_params();
  // This is where I want to get the token from $_SESSION
  return array( 'result' => 'Salaam. I can hear you.' );
}
```

Does the WP nonce authentication only work for users who are logged in to WP?

The request itself, in Dev Tools, does seem to be sending the cookie:

```
:authority: example.test
:method: POST
:path: /wp-json/myplugin-auth/v1/registeruser?
:scheme: https
accept: */*
(abridged)
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryoiTG77MAuyEduz00
cookie: PHPSESSID=8f4b03d3eaa814644ef29f7fea711a83
dnt: 1
origin: https://example.test
pragma: no-cache
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7)
```

And matches in the backend:

```php
session_id();
// 8f4b03d3eaa814644ef29f7fea711a83
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, once issue was that when *saving* the token I needed to retrieve to the `$_SESSION`, it was happening prior to `session_start()`, which I realized by running `session_id()` in xdebug. So then I hooked into the same wordpress `init` hook where this particular plugin runs `session_start()` if there isn't already a `$_SESSION` and put it at a lower priority:

Initiate session:

```php
add_action( 'init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\start_session', -2 );

function start_session() {
  if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ) {
      session_start();
  }
}
```

Access it again later:

```php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/example/authenticate") {
  add_action( 'init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\check_post_requests', 1 );
}
```

But there was another issue with how I was handling the Rest Request.

Missed this in the referenced WP Docs:

> It is important to keep in mind that this authentication method relies
> on WordPress cookies. As a result this method is only applicable when
> the REST API is used inside of WordPress and the current user is
> logged in. In addition, the current user must have the appropriate
> capability to perform the action being performed.

So, what we're doing, at least for the time being, is filtering [rest_authentication_headers](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#require-authentication-for-all-requests) and returning true once we determine there isn't already a `WP_Error`:

```php
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {
  if ( true === $result || is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
    return $result;
  }

  return true;
});
```

To be honest, I'm not completely confident that this doesn't create any security holes and I'm wondering, looking at the first part of the  [WP_Rest_server serve_request method](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2/src/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php#L261) if [Application Password](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/) authentication would be preferable.

Input welcome.